# Problema com Sistema de Recomendação em R

Tags: r

Estou tentando desenvolver um sistema de recomendação utilizando a linguagem R.

Basicamente, o sistema é de recomendação musical coleta informações de um arquivo onde existe uma certa quantidade de usuários e para cada usuário, uma contagem de vezes que ele ouviu determinado artista.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(data.table)
library(recommenderlab)

dados <- fread("dadosTreinamento.txt", header = TRUE, sep = "\t", fill = TRUE) #Dados carregados em variável

names(dados)[2:3] <- c("IdArtist", "IdUser")

dadosGrupo <- group_by(dados, IdUser, IdArtist) #Agrupando os dados

dadosGrupo2 <- summarise(dadosGrupo, count = n()) #Gerando tabela com soma da quantidade de vezes que cada usuário ouviu determinado artista
dadosGrupo2 <- as.data.frame(dadosGrupo2) #Convertendo dadosGrupo2 para data.frame

matrizAfinidade <- as(dadosGrupo2, "realRatingMatrix") #Matriz real de dados

Rec.model<-Recommender(matrizAfinidade, method = "UBCF")

usuarios <- length(unique(dadosGrupo2$IdUser))

listaRecomendacoes <- list(length(usuarios))

for (i in 1:usuarios) {
  itemRecomendado <- predict(Rec.model, matrizAfinidade[i,], n=5)
  listaRecomendacoes[i] <- as(itemRecomendado, "list")
}
```

Nesse trecho o programa gera a recomendação de 5 itens para os usuários.

Entretanto, quando tento visualizar a recomendação através do comando `View(listaRecomendacoes)`, o sistema apresenta apenas os itens recomendados e onde deveria ficar a informação do usuário para o qual o sistema recomendou, fica apenas a palavra "character", como é possível ver na figura abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O arquivo de dados dos usuários que estou usando está [neste link](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/18CvNXblNPcrfvaD9O9I8BoPnmsreRFsQ?usp=sharing).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bote um colchete a mais em `listaRecomendacoes` para que ele receba a lista inteira e não só conteúdo. Aí os IDs dos usuários são os nomes das listas.

```
listaRecomendacoes <- vector('list', usuarios) #inicializa uma lista vazia do tamanho de usuarios

for (i in 1:usuarios) {
  itemRecomendado <- predict(Rec.model, matrizAfinidade[i,], n=5)
  listaRecomendacoes[[i]] <- as(itemRecomendado, "list") #passa os valores para a lista
}

names(listaRecomendacoes[[1]]) #pega o ID do usuário 1
sapply(listaRecomendacoes, names)#vetor com os IDs dos usuários
```

Comment: Obrigado Jorge Mendes. Na verdade, acrescentando apenas os colchetes a listaRecomendacoes já deu certo!